# Parsing value from razor paze to action method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

My application read a list of records (applications) from a database and shows it on the screen. It's loaded in a partial view ( _ViewAllpartial.cshtml ) and embedded in the Index.cshtml. Every record had a delete button and when this button is clicked a modal popup appears. After confirming the modal, the record should be deleted from the database. My problem is that the ID of the application is not parsed to the code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        var applicationID;

        console.log("Document Ready starting....");

        $(document).on("click", "#modalDeleteButtonX", function (event) {
            console.log("applicationID to Delete: " + applicationID);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "Applications")",
                data:  applicationID,
                dataType: "int",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    console.log("failure");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log("error: " + response.responseText);
                }
            });

        });

        $('#modal-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);        // Button that triggered the modal
            applicationID = button.data("id");                 // Get id of the button
            $('#ItemToDelete').val(applicationID);
        });

        console.log("Document Ready finished....");
    });

</script>
```

Above the javascript which is located in the _ViewAllPartial file. When I click the confirmation-button on the modal dialog, the JS-function is called. In the dev tools I see a line *applicationID to Delete : 52* which is the correct ID. So far so good.

```
    public IActionResult OnPostDeleteAsync( int applicationId)
    {
        if (applicationId == 0)
            return Page();

        int affectedRows = _applicationRepository.DeleteApplication(applicationId);
        return Page();
    }
```

This is the action method on the Index.cshtml-file which is called, cause it stops when I put a breakpoint on it. When I hover the parameter *int applicationID* is it always 0 ( default int. value.

Am I missing something? I searched and tried several solutions for hours and hours, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Hi @kouwerp, I think what your description has many mistakes. You said use razor pages, if you use OnPostDeleteAsync in `.cshtml.cs `file, it is impossible to use `@Url.Action("Delete", "Applications")`. Because `OnPostDeleteAsync` here is a handler not a controller action. Also in razor pages, you need add `RequestVerificationToken` header when using ajax otherwise you cannot hit the handler and make 400 error.  Please confirm your code and share details to us.

Answer (score 0):

try this ajax

```
          $.ajax({
             url:  '/?handler=Delete',
             data: {  applicationId: applicationID },
             success: function (result) {
                   .....
```

and fix the action header

```
public JsonResult OnGetDelete(int applicatonId)
{
 int affectedRows = _applicationRepository.DeleteApplication(applicationId);
  if( affectedRows >0) return new JsonResult("Deleted!");
  return new JsonResult("Failed!");
}
```

you can't return page using ajax. So it is better for you to use a submit button intstead.

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately the value remains zero

Comment: are you sure that it hits breackpoint inside or OnPostDeleteAsync?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it stops at OnPostDeleteAsync

Comment: stops or getting inside of  OnPostDeleteAsync? Razor pages ajax route is very tricky, it usually usess a handler

Comment: It's getting inside the method and I can step through the lines of code.

Perhaps there is a better way to execute the Action Method to delete the code, but I'm not aware of it since I'm new to ASP.Net Core - razor page

Comment: @kouwerp try the second variant ,  see my answer and pls let me what is working for you.

Comment: I have to adjust my answer about getting into the action method. This was caused by the Form-tag around the modal-dialog. But when I remove this and only use the JS-AJAX call, an error is shown in the DevTools Console: 

XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://localhost:44378/applications/?action=delete&amp;controller=applications
Line Number 1, Column 1: